# Get exect match and matched data from mongodb using $text

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, debug-mode

I am trying to use the following query in MongoDB.
**1)** db.products.createIndex({ name: "text",category.name':"text"})
   
 this will create a Index.
**2)** Now my query is 
       db.products.find({$text:{$search:"Sun moon Tapestry"}})

this will bring data according to Sun,moon, and Tapestry.

**3)** but i want to get data like this.

     
         **a)** first all data row in exect match
                Sun moon Tapestry
     
         **b)** then after that Sun,moon and Tapestry will show up

(NOTE: DB call should be one time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the matching textScore to sort the resultset:

```
db.products
       .find({ $text : { $search : "Sun moon Tapestry" } }, { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } })
       .sort({score:{$meta: "textScore"}})
```

Since you have 2 text indexes you can also define weights for `name` and `category.name`.
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/

PS:There is nothing related angularjs

**EDIT**: if you use Mongoose the query stays the same, you have to query your model

```
YourProduct
       .find({ $text : { $search : "Sun moon Tapestry" } }, { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } })
       .sort({score:{$meta: "textScore"}})
       .exec(function (err, data) {
            if (err)
                res.json(err);
            else {
                res.json(data)
            }
        });
```

For the angular integration you can create a Service which uses $http https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http and do your ajax call.

Comment: This looks great and got expected results. this is only working in my terminal can you please enject in angularjs while sending query to express to fetch the results. This is really impressive.

Comment: Yes i used same like this perhaps i did mistake somewhere in my code because of lot's of product conditions in single DB call. it's working in my terminal will follow it when i resolved sophisticated code structure. Thanks again!!.